# CSS3 Background-size Not working but VISIBLE in Firebug - Firefox 3.6

Tags: html, css

I'm using the new CSS3 spec "background-size" to have a background image that slightly overflows the size of the page.  It's working fine in webkit (Chrome & Safari) but the "-moz-background-size" property is not working at all in Firefox. The unusual thing is, if you view the site live, the "-moz-background-size" property **IS** showing when viewing the site with Firebug! The FF docs say that it is supported as of 3.6 and I'm running 3.6.

Here's my code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1150px) { 
/* special sytles for browser windows less than 1150px */
body{
    -o-background-size: 130%; -webkit-background-size: 130%; -khtml-background-size: 130%; -moz-background-size: 130%;
    background-size: 130%;
}
#trans_fake{
    -o-background-size: 130%; -webkit-background-size: 130%; -khtml-background-size: 130%; -moz-background-size: 130%;  
    background-size: 130%;
}
}
```

Any debug suggestions?

**EDIT**
I'm more confused now... QuirksMode.org is reporting a "white" box rather than red or green to indicate css3 background-size percentage-based compatibility in Firefox 3.6 :(
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/background.html

Comment: See my EDIT above, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a CSS mistake on my part, I had a

```
body{
background:url() top center no-repeat;
}
```

later down the page which was somehow overridding the Firefox "-moz-background-size: 130%".  So, if you're having trouble, give

```
body{
background-size: 130% !important;
}
```

to your CSS in Firefox and it might solve the problem.

Answer (score 21):

I was running into the same issue this morning and what solved it for me was making sure the image was listed ahead of the background-size property. It was working in one instance and not in another. Why? The order of the CSS properties. Try this.

```
.front #logo {
  height: 58px;
  width:323px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background:url(../imgs/logo-x2-retina.png) no-repeat;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
  -webkit-background-size:100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was having this same problem when setting properties using javascript -- setting the url after the backgroundsize wasn't working.  Had no idea what was going on until I read this.

Comment: That's because later declarations overwrite the others. For example: `background:blue; background:red`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties   take a look at the **Tricky Edge Cases**

Comment: Solved the same issue for me in the latest chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Your page looks the same to me in Firefox 3.6, Firefox 4.0 and Chrome, but I can't see any `background-size` in any of it?  Do you have a link to a page that actually demonstrates the problem?

My initial suggestion would be to specify both width and height and see if that works:

```
-moz-background-size: 130% 130%;
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt!  Unfortunately that doesn't do it :(  I had posted a link to the live site in the original question.  Here it is again: http://anasmadance.com.s66112.gridserver.com/  specifying both axis (as per your suggestion) did not fix the issue.

Comment: background size registers for me in all browsers - line 139 of style.css: http://anasmadance.com.s66112.gridserver.com/wp/wp-content/themes/anasma_custom/style.css

Comment: @Brian OK, I didn't see the media query and I was looking at it full screen.  I see -moz-background-size in Firebug but it's reporting as `-moz-background-size: 70% auto;` rather than the 130%, this may just be a bug.  If you try to make the background smaller (say 50%) does your page do the same thing in all browsers?

Comment: LOL.  Robert, I changed it to 70% for debugging.  I thought maybe Firefox was not registering values over 100% for background-size so I tried smaller instead.  Still there is no change on the site when I update that rule.  It works in Safari and Chrome - changing it back to 130% in Firefox now.

Comment: @Brian OK, one mystery cleared up then!  I think the best way to proceed is to try and create a simple test case - just a simple page with only the background image - and see if the problem still occurs.  If it doesn't then you can start adding complexity to see what triggers the issue, but like I said, this may just turn out to be a bug (this is experimental stuff, after all).

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS background from

```
background:url(../imgs/logo-x2-retina.png) no-repeat;
```

to

```
background-image:url(../imgs/logo-x2-retina.png);
```

Answer (score -1):

I am wrote: 
background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
And all work

Comment: `background-size: 100% 100%, auto;` is for multiple background images, which was not mentioned in the question.  The `,` delimiter indicates setting size for a second background.