# Background-size workaround for Safari 4

Tags: css, background, safari, size, compatibility

background-size is not compatible with Safari 4. (this can be seen here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover) I have no clue how to make this, so I was wondering if someone knows a solution to make it work with this browser. I am trying to use an image with background-size:cover. Css or jQuery would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Just curious as to why you're targeting Safari 4? That's at least two major revisions behind (6.0 just came out), and it's never been a hugely popular browser to begin with. I have to think traffic total would be a tiny fraction of 1%. It also looks like Safar 4.1 implemented background-size correctly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size

Comment: I didn't really know it was so unpopular (or unused  nowadays). Thanks for both notices, I guess if there is a solution with version 4.1 I don't really have to worry.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't sweat it. If your site, for some reason, has a large percentage of Safari 4.0 users, go back and figure something out - but I doubt that's the case :)

Comment: @chipcullen heard of Ipad 1? cannot upgrade the browsers i think.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem on safari, both on Windows and Mac, and I was using

```
background-size: 100%
```

Then I tried vendor prefixes which seems to solved the problem on Safari. But when I tested on Mac on Firefox, then the same problem appeared. Even on IE9 :(

But using [Brian's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717400/css3-background-size-not-working-but-visible-in-firebug-firefox-3-6/4786843#4786843) advice:

```
background-size: 100% !important;
```

solved the problem.